# Replace value in a list

Tags: python, replace

I want to replace a value in the list

```
dem = [<p class="left-text padding-left-10">
<a href="/people" class="red-text">See all people</a>
</p>, <p class="left-text padding-left-10">
<a href="/tv" class="red-text" style="display:inline;">See all bio TV</a>
<span class="divider">&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
<a href="/tv/daily-schedule" class="red-text" style="display:inline;">See schedule </a>
</p>, <p class="left-text bottom-flyout-video-padding">
<a href="/videos" class="red-text ">See all videos</a>
</p>, <p class="left-text padding-left-10">]

dem.replace('<a href','<!--')
```

This gives me an error. I know its a list. How can i replace all values of `a href` with `<!--`.

Comment: are the values in your list quoted? also what error does it give you

Comment: Im running it thorugh flask so i dont get the traceback. Yes it does have quotes.How can you replace values in a list.

Answer (score 4):

You can use list comprehension, which will give you a new list with required replacement:

```
[elem.replace("<a href", "<!--") for elem in dem]
```

Comment: Ok there's a change. The objects inside the list which i need to change are of<class 'BeautifulSoup.Tag'> type. How can i change them.

Comment: @user2707082. That you should have told earlier in the question.

Comment: No i just realised. Can you edit your answer.

Comment: @user2707082. I don't know about BeautifulSoup. So, no I don't know the answer.

Answer (score 0):

you should iterate iterate over your list and use replace on each list item individually

**Example**

```
for i in range(len(dem)):
    dem[i] = dem[i].replace('<a href','<!--')
```

Comment: did you actually try this? dont think it works

Comment: Yeah i thought that would work too but its a beautiful soup clas tag